# Jquery, filter and hide elements, howto sort these ".hidden" elements to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

currently I have got a apache wicket navigation tree showing one root node with a few children and a simple text input for filtering the tree items.

Upon filtering the not matching items are hidden via adding a css class. This works pretty well.

I have problems with sorting the unhidden items to top after applying the filter, so after try and error for more than an hour, I thought: "Let's ask those nice and willing people over at StaggzOverflowz again".

UPDATE: I posted a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/polzifer/ypu9K/

The tree looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="filter"/>
<div class="navigation"> 
  <wicket:panel>
   -RootNode
     -Child with a link inside
     -Child with a link inside
     -Child with a link inside
     -...
   </wicket:panel>
</div>
```

Above that tree, I have a simple text input which on "keyup" is filtering the tree with javascript:

```
function filterList(){
    var count = 0;

    /*
    * for every link item in the navigation tree check, if they match the search entry
    * and add the class ".hidden{ visibility: hidden;}" to it's enclosing parent 
    * element
    */
    jQuery(".navigation a").each(function () {
        if(jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(jQuery("#filter").val(),"i"))<0){
            jQuery(this).parents(".wicket-tree-content").addClass("hidden");
        }else{
            jQuery(this).parents(".wicket-tree-content").removeClass("hidden");
            count++;
        }
    });

   //Detach children from the navigation, sort them and append them again
   //(we have a <wicket:panel> element around the children)
   jQuery('.navigation').children().children().detach().sort(
        function(a,b) {
            var condA = jQuery(a).hasClass("hidden");
            var condB = jQuery(b).hasClass("hidden");
            var result =  0;

            if(condA == condB){
             result = -1;
            }
            if(condA != condB){
             result = 1;
            }

            return result;
    }).appendTo(jQuery('.navigation').children());
}
```

Comment: Can you please post an example on jsFiddle?It's not clear where is the error

Comment: That will be hard to state on jsfiddle as an example, but I will try....

My main concern is why the sorting algorithm is not working propperly.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti jsfiddle is up.

Comment: I corrected your algorithm for sorting in a way i think is more correct but it still doesn't give me the result i wish: the not hidden values are always in the end http://jsfiddle.net/ypu9K/1/

Comment: I updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/polzifer/ypu9K/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/polzifer/ypu9K/5/  Removed the sorting as it is unnessecary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick for now was to detach all ".hidden" elements and append them to the end...

http://jsfiddle.net/polzifer/ypu9K/4/